# How to change an applications icon in the taskbar in SparkyLinux?

Tags: openbox, icons, tint2

I am using SparkyLinux. It's their minimal GUI that uses Openbox for the window manager and Tint2 for the panel. I dislike the default icon for the Geany text editor, so I changed it in the .desktop file. Now, when I open my applications menu (jgmenu) or when I add Geany to the tint2 panel, the new icon appears.

However when I launch Geany using either of these two starting points, the icon that appears in the list of active apps in the panel remains the stock Geany icon. How can I change that icon to use my preferred icon?

[image]

Comment: Sparky Linux. It's their minimal GUI that uses Openbox for the window manager and Tint2 for the panel.  So, the icon I want to change is the one that appears in the Tint2 panel while the application is running.